# My border around my image is not fitting the image

Tags: html, css, border, jsfiddle

the border around my image is not fitting and i believe a direct full screen jsfiddle link will be of use, the jsfiddle link will have 2 images it is the second one which is not working i have uploaded the second picture so that it is visible
https://jsfiddle.net/Nafis241/8h60bsg7/5/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/Nafis241/8h60bsg7/5/

```
    #imgCent {
        text-align: center;
        border:5px solid #000000;
 }
```

Comment: What is your desired effect?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/8h60bsg7/7/

Comment: i want the board to fit the image like the one above but i haven't provided a picture the one above

Comment: yes that is what i'm looking for if you upload it as an answer ill approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the `#imgCent` in the wrong place.

Add `#imgCent` to the `<img>` itself instead of the `<div>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/8h60bsg7/7/

Answer (score -1):

Try to re frame your question to get a better understanding of what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please wait until you have enough rep to post comments appropriately.

Comment: OK Adam seems to have answered the question ill keep that in mind for next time thanks for the feedback

Comment: Hungerstar... No one is fighting with you here. Easy tiger. Keep it cool